# How to shuffle the rows of an excel spreadsheet using VBscript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, shuffle

I am having an excel spreadsheet with some data that has been ordered/sorted. I wish to undo this ordering by dynamically shuffling the rows using VBscript.
Is there a way I can do this?

Example : Suppose I am having 10 subjects and each subject is having 100 questions. They are all in the excel sheet in subject order wise and I need to shuffle them up so that they appear randomly without being ordered subject-wise using VBscript.

Comment: Do you have an example excel sheet?  I have an idea but don't have the time to mock up the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Assign a random number to each entry and sort on that.

Comment: can you give any example of random shuffle?

Answer (score 0):

Random logic is really simple, 
use **rand() on column  -> then sort using Filter.**

- 'Applying Random formula on the first column of the cell
   oReadSheet.Cells(iRow, 1) = "=Rand()"
- 'Sorting 
  Call oReadSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oReadSheet.Columns(1), , xlAscending)

Refer the working code:- 
[Example for randomization of Excel data using vbscript](http://www.ufthelp.com/2015/07/how-to-randomize-rows-of-data-in-excel.html)